# Classnotfoundexception java inside package?

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, netbeans-8

I have a stupid question but please help:

I have a java package called users.

This package has two classes:

First class: Account

```
package users;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Account implements Serializable{

private String username;
private String password;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

The second class is too big to post ... so i will clarify that the second class make some implementation and take an object from Account class.

When running my application it throws an error says:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Account
```

however, when i test this code in the default package it works fine. but you know using the default package is not always a good thing.

I am using NetBeans 8.0.2 editor.

any solutions?

Comment: Where is the class file of the 2nd java file generated?  They should both end up in the same folder.

Comment: both of them generated successfully sir.... in the same folder.

Comment: Do you have an import users.Account in the other class?

Comment: @Keammoort all classes are in the same package so no need to use import users.Account but anyway i tried it and same problem exists.

Comment: let me clarify more: the second file is called employee ... well ... the folder containing the class files .. its contents like this (Account, Employee$1, Employee$2,Employee$3,Employee$4,Employee,Employee.form)